# This Question relates to Center of mass and CM frame conceptual problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames

## Question

There are some passengers inside a stationary railway compartment .The track is friction less .The center of mass of the compartment itself is C1(without the passengers ) , while center of mass of compartment plus passengers system is C2. If the passengers move about inside compartment along the track .
Then

> A>Both C1 and C2 move with respect to ground 
>  
>   B>Neither C1 nor C2 will move with respect to ground 
>   C>C1 will move but C2 will be stationary with respect to the ground  
>   D>C2 will move but C1 will be stationary with respect to ground

## My trial

As the passengers are moving c1 will be same as since the compartment is still there and due to their movement its own CM will not change and as people are moving C2 must change as configuration changed.
  Giving my senses answer D but its C 


 I am unable to think beyond what is possible cause and why I am wrong here and also its not a Homework Question but rather my self study question.
Also Some advice on how to deal with such questions would be helpful if possible

Comment: The total center of mass (C2) will not move because there isn't an external force applied in the direction of motion. Since C2 is fixed, and people are moving then logically C1 must counteract the motion of the passengers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When people are moving inside the railway compartment, they are able to do so because of the reaction they get when they applied force on the floor as per *Newton's Third Law*.

Now, the important thing here is to chose a *system* on which you will apply Newton's laws. If you chose the railway compartment together with people inside it as a system (call it System 1),the net force on this system is zero. This is because there is no external force (they mentioned in the problem that the track is frictionless, so if the railway compartment accelerates due to a force on it, it is not offered any other external force by the track) and internal force add up to zero using Newton's third law.

Now, as total force on System 1 is zero, the center of mass $C2$ remains stationary in the frame of reference of ground.

If you chose the railway compartment as System 2 (without people), then the forces by people will be taken as external force. This net external force accelerates the center of mass $C1$ with respect to ground.

You can imagine this in your mind by noting that as people step to one side, they exert a force on railway compartment in the opposite direction, which will accelerate the railway compartment in that direction causing the center of mass to be exactly where it was if it was initially at rest.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that since C2 doesn't change because it is both the train car and the passengers, C1 is being altered with respect to station.

(C2 = center of (C1 + mass of passengers)) stays constant

(C1 = center of mass of car) alone moves as passengers do